# IntelliJ Webstorm Terminal color bug

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, webstorm

I'm starting to get this weird color terminating bug in the terminal and I tried everything I can think of to fix it.

It looks like the color doesn't get reset when outputted by some command. Does anyone know how to fix it?

I even tried making my .bash_profile PS! really simple `export PS1="\W: "`, different terminals, cmd, git-bash, all are experiencing this issue.

This only happens inside the editor's terminal/run window. If I start my terminals externally they are fine.

[image: git-bash]
[image: cmd]

Answer (score 2):

Seems you have some custom colors set for screen text and background in Windows cmd console properties. See [IDEA-145236](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145236) and [IDEA-124182](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124182) for details. The solution is to set cmd console colors back to defaults - by either editing the Windows registry key or by modifying default cmd console properties

Answer (score 0):

Resetting my console settings by deleting the entire HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console key from the registry to do a "hard reset" on all my terminals was the suggested solution.

Another suggestion was to just delete one key, `ScreenColors`. I didn't try this because this issue was plaguing all my terminals.

No one knows the exact reason for this bug, and they're not even trying to fix it.

Thank's lena for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This has been driving me nuts this week, too.  I use the terminal a load, so it's annoying to have to keep closing; I've reset the windows cmd colours back to the difficult-to-read schema to save webstorm for now but this really kinda sucks.